# How to derive the distribution corresponding to an experiment?

Tags: distributions

I want to model the following experiment and derive the corresponding distribution of it.

Consider a situation where a number of backup copies are made of a hard drive (and all stored in the same location) and by some random event, each bit of each of the backups is randomly corrupted (i.e. randomly set to 0 or 1) with a probability of 0.1. If we have 5 copies, what is the likelihood that we can correctly reconstruct a particular bit using a majority scheme (i.e. if we assume that the most frequently occurring bit is the correct one)? How many copies would we have to make in order to e able to reconstruct a given byte with a probability higher than 99.9%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define

- $N$ - number of backup hard drive, I'm assuming its odd
- $p$ - probability of specific bit not being corrupted
- $S_{i,k}$ - i-th bit in k-th hard drive not corrupted
- $R_{i,k}$ - i-th bit in k-th hard drive correct (because if it is corrupted it can still show correct value if I understood correctly)
- $W_i$ - i-th bit reconstructed correctly

All above events are equal to $1$ if they hold and $0$ otherwise .So we have

$$P(R_{i,k} = 0) = P(S_{i,k} = 0)P(R_{i,k} = 0 | S_{i,k} = 0) = \frac{1 - p}{2}$$

Since if bit is corrupted we have $50\%$ chance it is still correct (if I understood correctly)

$$P(W_i = 1) = P\Big(\sum_{k = 1}^NR_{i,k} \ge \frac{N+1}{2}\Big) = P\Big(\sum_{k = 1}^N(1 - R_{i,k}) \le \frac{N-1}{2}\Big) = P(X \le \frac{N-1}{2})$$

Of course $P((1 - R_{i,k}) = 1) = P(R_{i,k} = 0) = \frac{1 - p}{2}$. So $X$ has a distribution $Binom(N,\frac{1 - p}{2})$

For your case we have for $X \sim Binom(5, 0.05)$

$$P(W_i = 1) = P(X \le 2) = 0.9988419 \eqsim 99.88\%$$

If you take $N = 7$ and $X \sim Binom(7, 0.05)$ it is already better than $99.9\%$

$$P(X \le 3) = 0.9998064 \eqsim 99.98\%$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any source for reading more questions like this?